NetBeans Xdebug working in one project but not another
I have NetBeans 21 installed (yes I know it's a little old but I don't believe that's the issue) with PHP and Xdebug.
I've got a situation where the debugger will start on one project but not on another and I can't work out why.
ALL settings are identical (except for directories and local URL).
When I click Debug Project on Project A, loads immediately, launches the browser and takes me to the home page of the site.
When I click Debug Project on Project B, sits there with the dreaded "Waiting for Connection".
Both sites same version of PHP.  Anyone ever experienced this?  Any suggested solutions?
